# what is `Normalize` for in PyTorch transfer learning tutorial?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, pytorch

in [this pytorch tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html), there is `transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])`, what is the purpose of this?

(i removed it and the code still works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are mean and standard deviation used to standardize each channel of the images from [IMAGENET](https://www.image-net.org/) used to train the [torchvision pretrained models](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/models.html).

Since the models were trained using this preprocessing step, it is useful to apply it also when using those models for transfer learning on new data.